# Calling stored procedure using hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure defined in a package. The procedure accepts two parameters, one is a cursor:

```
create or replace PACKAGE TESTPACKAGE IS
TYPE STATUSCURSOR IS REF CURSOR;
PROCEDURE TestProcedure(cId IN VARCHAR2,
StatusCursonVal IN OUT STATUSCURSOR);
END;
```

**I am calling the procedure like this:**

```
String sql = "EXEC TESTPACKAGE.TestProcedure('testId')";
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
        List list = query.list();
```

**It is returning the following error:**

13:03:25,338 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Hibernate: EXEC TESTPACKAGE .TestProcedure('testId')

13:03:25,749 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) SQL Error: 900, SQLState: 42000
13:03:25,750 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-3) ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

And the exception states "Could not extract resultSet".

I have tried to execute the procedure in SQL Developer but it failed. It seems the problem is I am executing the procedure with only one parameter but it also has an IN OUT parameter.

**Please help how can I invoke this procedure.**

Regards,
Anirban.

Answer (score 0):

As per hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-sp), correct way to call a stored procedure is -

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery( "sp_count_phones");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter( "personId", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter( "phoneCount", Long.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

query.setParameter("personId", 1L);

query.execute();
Long phoneCount = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue("phoneCount");
```

For executing Oracle stored procedure with cursor refer following example -

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery( "sp_person_phones" );
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter( 1, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN );
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter( 2, Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR );
query.setParameter( 1, 1L );

query.execute();
List<Object[]> postComments = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: But how will I pass a cursor to a stored procedure?

Comment: Getting the following error after implementing like you suggested, Dialect [org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect] not known to support REF_CURSOR parameters

Comment: What is your hibernate version ?

Comment: I am using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final.

Comment: Shouldn't your out parameter be of type `SYS_REFCURSOR` instead of `STATUSCURSOR` ?

Comment: STATUSCURSOR is a local variable of type REF_CURSOR